# Pygame rectangle move

Tags: python, pygame, move, rect

I'm quite new to pygame. I managed to create a class which draws a rect.

I'll be using this class to make multiple shapes, and try to move a shape when it's clicked. But before I create more shapes, I have to be sure that I can move it. 
But I didn't succeed in moving just even one shape.

**Example.py**

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# Global variables

whiteColor = (255, 255, 255)
darkColor = (51, 51, 51)
lightColor = (83, 83, 83)
blackColor = (0, 0, 0)

# Classes

class obj_disk(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, blackColor, (0,0,234,32))

# Methods

def game_settings():
    """
    Manage all the main settings for the game.
    @Global screen: The main window
    """

    global screen

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Towers of Hanoi")
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
    pygame.time.wait(10)

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
    screen.fill(darkColor)

    create_objects()

    pygame.display.update()

def create_objects():
    """
    Creates all the objects that are required to play the game.
    """

    # Create disks
    disk_array = []
    for i in range(0,1):
        disk_array.append(obj_disk())

    disk_array[0].rect.move(40,50)

def game_start():
    """
    Starts the game and handles all the events.
    """

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_settings()
    game_start()
```

Comment: What's the problem? Nothing happens? Crashes?

Comment: The shape doesn't move. No Crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `while True` block in your `game_start` function, but the loop doesn't actually paint the screen. In fact, your loop doesn't call `game_settings()` to update the state of your rectangle either.

Your main game loop needs to, generally speaking, update the state of the objects and then draw the screen.

You need some incarnation of `pygame.display.update`, the specifics of which I don't remember because I haven't done pygame in quite a while.

Comment: I don't think that that is the solution because i do call pygame.display.update after i tried to move the rect.
Edit: I just tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: But `game_settings` is not being called in your while loop. So what your program does is call `game_settings`, create the rectangle, move it, update the display. Then you call `game_start` and inside your while loop, your "main game loop" so to speak, you do nothing but wait for a QUIT event. Try putting a `print("updating display")` before your `pygame.display.update()` call and see that it only gets called once.

Comment: I know. But as you say: 'So what your program does is call game_settings, create the rectangle, move it, update the display.' But somehow it doesn't move.

Comment: That is because you are calling `rect.move()` before you update the display. So before the display gets drawn, the rectangle has already moved. It is drawn in its new position, and never appears to move. Additionally, you wouldn't see it move, even if you moved the display update call before and after the move, because it would be a near instaneous blip right as the app started up.

Comment: As I said before, it doesn't move. The shape appears at (0,0) instead of (40,50)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues. The main ones are:

```
disk_array[0].rect.move(40,50)
```

Look at the documentation for [`Rect.move`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move):

> Returns a new rectangle that is moved by the given offset.

Since you don't use the returned value of the call to `move`, this line does nothing. If you want to actually change the `Rect`, use [`move_ip`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip):

> Same as the Rect.move() method, but operates in place.

so change that line to

```
disk_array[0].rect.move_ip(40,50)
```

The next problem is that you don't draw the rect to the screen after changing it. You just draw to the screen in the initializer of `obj_disk`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, blackColor, (0,0,234,32))
```

If you really want to use a class, you should just set `rect` in the initializer. Now it's up to you if you want to handle the actual drawing inside the `obj_disk` class or not, and if you want to, you could simply add a `draw` method, so the class looks like:

```
class obj_disk(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(0,0,234,32)
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, blackColor, self.rect)
```

Now you can draw the objects with

```
for obj in disk_array:
    obj.draw()
```

at the end of `create_objects`.

Note that `disk_array` is local to `create_objects`, so you can't access it outside of this function. This function should probably return the list of the objects so you can actually do something with them.